# Geometric interpretation of tracing

Tags: tensor

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Is it true that for any symmetric 2-tensor $\alpha$ we have:
$Trace_g(\alpha)=1/\omega_n\int_{S^{n-1}}\alpha(V,V)dvol(V)$
where $w_n$ is the volume of $S^{n-1}$?
Thank you.

Comment: You are off by a factor of $n$, assuming that you are on an $n$-manifold.  However, this has nothing to do with Riemannian geometry because you are doing your calculations at a point.  This is a linear algebra fact.  To make it right, you'd need to evaluate the left hand side at a point $x\in M$ (and divide it by $n$), and, on the right hand side, integrate over the unit $V\in S_x\subset T_xM$.

Comment: See http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1367/can-a-10k-help-copy-an-answer-to-math-se/1368#1368

Comment: An unsuccessful attempt to migrate to MSE was made.

Answer (score 2):

A follow-up to Robert Bryant's comments. Let $S^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere in some tangent space with inner product $g$. Let $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be an orthonormal frame and let $V_i=\langle V,e_i\rangle$.
For $i\neq j$, $\int_{S^{n-1}}V_{i}V_{j}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)  =0$ since the
integrand is odd with respect to reflection about the coordinate hyperplane $\left\{  V_{i}=0\right\}
$. Taking $i=j$, we get $\int_{S^{n-1}}V_{i}^{2}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)
=\frac{\omega_{n}}{n}$ since this expression is independent of $i$ and since
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{S^{n-1}}V_{i}^{2}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)  =\int_{S^{n-1}
}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)  =\omega_{n}$, using $|V|^2=1$. We conclude with $\alpha_{ij}=\alpha (e_i,e_j)$ that
$$
\int_{S^{n-1}}\alpha\left(  V,V\right)  \operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)  =\sum
_{i,j=1}^{n}\int_{S^{n-1}}\alpha_{ij}V_{i}V_{j}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{S^{n-1}}\alpha_{ii}V_{i}^{2}\operatorname{dvol}\left(  V\right)
=\frac{\omega_{n}}{n}\operatorname{Trace}{}_{g}(\alpha).
$$
I once gave this formula as a homework problem in a Riemannian geometry class at UCSD and learned this short proof from one of the students.

A reference for this formula, in relation to differential geometry, is the book "Riemannian geometry" by Gallot, Hulin, and Lafontaine.

Happy Thanksgiving, November 28, 2013.

**In response to the question being put on hold as off-topic by Ricardo Andrade, Andrey Rekalo, Olivier Benoist, Stefan Kohl, David White:**

A few elementary examples of tracing in Riemannian geometry are as follows.

Acting on functions and tensors, the trace of the Hessian operator $\nabla
^{2}$ is the (rough) Laplacian $\Delta$. A trace of the covariant derivative
of a tensor is its divergence.

A trace of the Riemann curvature $4$-tensor $\operatorname{Rm}$ is the Ricci
$2$-tensor $\operatorname{Ric}$. The trace of the Ricci tensor is the scalar curvature.

For the second Bianchi identity $\nabla_{\lbrack V}\operatorname{Rm}%
(W,X],Y,Z)=0$ (square brackets denotes cyclically permuting and summing),
tracing twice yields the contracted second Bianchi identity
$\operatorname{div}(\operatorname{Ric})=\frac{1}{2}dR$.

The trace is important in the irreducible decomposition of tensors, including
both the curvature and its covariant derivatives. It is useful to consider the
trace-free part of a tensor. The Weyl tensor is totally trace-free.

The mean curvature is the trace of the second fundamental form.

Under a variation of a metric, its volume form evolves by one-half of the
trace of the variation.

In the study of the partial differential equations arising from equations
involving curvature, covariantly differentiating and tracing is useful.

Comment: Re: your "response", undoubtedly the closers know that the notion of "trace" is useful in mathematics. But as you indicated yourself in your answer, this is essentially a "homework question", and certainly does not fit the [MO of MO](http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic)  (pun intended). (The operative word in the closure reason is "research".)

Comment: To Willie Wong: I respectfully disagree with you.